# Extension function using wrong class

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to use [QuickPermissions-Kotlin](https://github.com/QuickPermissions/QuickPermissions-Kotlin/blob/master/quickpermissions-kotlin/src/main/java/com/livinglifetechway/quickpermissions_kotlin/PermissionsManager.kt), but I can't seem to figure out how to call it.

I have:

```
class ScanFragment : ListFragment() {
    // ...
    private fun scanLeDevice(enable: Boolean) = runWithPermissions(
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

(My complete source is https://gist.github.com/astronouth7303/e676fb42644ed036f4af2f9516b556f2)

Where `runWithPermissions()` is declared as:

```
fun Context?.runWithPermissions(
        vararg permissions: String,
        options: QuickPermissionsOptions = QuickPermissionsOptions(),
        callback: () -> Unit
): Any? {
    return runWithPermissionsHandler(this, permissions, callback, options)
}

fun Fragment?.runWithPermissions(
        vararg permissions: String,
        options: QuickPermissionsOptions = QuickPermissionsOptions(),
        callback: () -> Unit
): Any? {
    return runWithPermissionsHandler(this, permissions, callback, options)
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
>
> - `public fun Context?.runWithPermissions(vararg permissions: String, options: QuickPermissionsOptions = ..., callback: () -> Unit): Any?` defined in `com.livinglifetechway.quickpermissions_kotlin`

(To be clear, the inheritance is `ScanFragment` -> `ListFragment` -> `Fragment` -> `Object`)

So why is it trying to use `Context.runWithPermissions()` inside of a `Fragment` when `Fragment.runWithPermissions()` exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `runWithPermissions` extension for `Fragment` seems to have been added in this library just 7 days ago, in [this commit](https://github.com/QuickPermissions/QuickPermissions-Kotlin/commit/ea4b85b98b2940a3ede80c5dc0e5d2688ac121aa). Using it works fine if you have the release that was published right after, `0.2.0`:

```
implementation 'com.github.quickpermissions:quickpermissions-kotlin:0.2.0'
```

Perhaps you're still on version `0.1.0` of the library, which didn't have this feature?

Comment: Yup. Now I feel like a flippin' idiot. Thanks for pointing this out!